# Unable to click on icon using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

Here is the element I have in web page:

```
<div uib-popover-template="'isVeiwCompTemplate.html'" popover-is-
open="col.colDef.value[row.entity.index]" popover-placement="right" popover-
trigger="outsideClick" class="fti-view-composition icon-fti_plusSign ng-
scope"></div>
```

[***** Please take a look on the actual object in image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikLWd.png)

I am unable to click this icon. I have tried

```
var ele = element(by.css("button[ng-click*=col.colDef.value]"));
    ele.click();
```

Also I have tried using the class xpath

```
"//div[@class='fti-view-composition icon-fti_plusSign ng-
scope']"
```

Can you please help me to find some solution???

Comment: You are missing quotes around the attribute value in your first selector... but i also dont see `ng-click` in the HTML provided?

Comment: Added the actual object using screenshot, please refer the image this might help you to understand the concern.

Comment: ok.. i still dont see an `ng-click` attribute.  Your HTML provided is a `div`, but the selector you are trying is `button[ng-click...`?  I'm confused

Comment: oh yeah let me fix that. thanks Gunderson

Comment: Here is the error I got after replacing button with div : Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.I hope this should work

```
    element.all(by.repeater('((colRenderIndex, col) in 
       colContainer.renderedColumns')).then(function(renderedColumns) {
       renderedColumns[1].click();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = element(by.css('.icon-fti_plusSign'));
// or
var element = $('.icon-fti_plusSign');

element.click();
```

Comment: Let me try this today

Comment: Andriyze : how can put an index in it as I got more than 1 items?